# Jquery OR || operator not working

Tags: jquery

it's a really simple question. The or operator is not working, i am trying to display a different function for both the title and amount field name. Thank you

```
$.each(x, function(i, field){
        if (field.name === "title" || "amount")
          {
            $( ".added-inquiry" ).find(".row:last-child").find(".column").find( ".added-inquiry-item").append(
                 '<input type="hidden" name="' + field.name + '" value="' + field.value + '"/>' +
                 '<span class="' + field.name + '">' + field.value + '</span>' + '<br>'
             );
        }
```

Comment: You should use `field.name === "title" || field.name === "amount"`.

Comment: Because of operator precedence, you're basically saying "if `field.name === "title"` is truthy or if `"amount"` is truthy, then ..."

Answer (score 1):

You either have to restate the condition like

```
if (field.name === "title" || field.name === "amount")
```

or you can use an array

```
if (["title","amount"].indexOf(field.name) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `||` like that.

You need to do:

```
if (field.name === "title" || field.name === "amount")
```

Each statement on either side of the OR are completely separate, and evaluate themselves to be a single boolean value, `true` or `false`. Therefore, `field.name === "title"` will evaluate itself to be `true` or `false`, and then `"amount"` will try to evaluate itself as `true` or `false`.

I believe anything non-empty and non-zero is treated as `true`, so your OR statement will always be true as `"amount"` will always evaluate to `true`.

You can also do:

```
if (["title", "amount"].indexOf(field.name) > -1)
```

This is especially useful if you have more than 2 values to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing like this:

```
temp = "title" || "amount"; // two "true" values, so "title" is assigned
if (field.name == temp);{ ... };
```

which is effectively:

```
temp = "title";
if (field.name == temp) { ... }
```

To test one varaible against multiple strings, you have to write out the individual tests directly:

```
if ((field.name == "title") || (field.name == "amount")) { ... }
```

and if you need to test against MANY items for which this kind of stuff  would get tedious, you can try an array:

```
if (["title", "amount", ...].indexOf(field.name) > -1) { ... }
```